# trying to write python code to solve quadratic formula, having some problems

Tags: python, quadratic

```
enter code here
import math
print("\nax^2+bx+c\n")
A=float(input("a: "))
B=float(input("b: "))
C=float(input("c: "))

d=math.sqrt((B**2)-4(A)(C))
answerA=(-B-d)/2*A

answerB=(-B+d)/2*A

print("the answers are ",answerA,"and",answerB)
```

I dont really understand what is happening, here is an image of the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTVwR.png)

main.py:7: SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
d=math.sqrt((B**2)-4(A)(C))

Comment: Replace `4(A)(C)` with `4*A*C`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be explicit with the multiplication signs.

```py
import math
print("\nax^2+bx+c\n")
A=float(input("a: "))
B=float(input("b: "))
C=float(input("c: "))

d=math.sqrt((B**2)-4*A*C)
answerA=(-B-d)/2*A

answerB=(-B+d)/2*A

print("the answers are ",answerA,"and",answerB)
```